# Asking advice on optimizing a while loop

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-integration

This is part of an algorithm regarding the [RKF method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method)

```
t = self.a
x = np.array(self.x0)
h = self.hmax

T = np.array( [t] )
X = np.array( [x] )
k= [0]*6
while t < self.b:

    if t + h > self.b:
        h = self.b - t
    
    k[0] = h * self.f(t, x)
    k[1] = h * self.f(t + a2 * h, x + b21 * k[0] )
    k[2] = h * self.f(t + a3 * h, x + b31 * k[0] + b32 * k[1])
    k[3] = h * self.f(t + a4 * h, x + b41 * k[0] + b42 * k[1] + b43 * k[2])
    k[4] = h * self.f(t + a5 * h, x + b51 * k[0] + b52 * k[1] + b53 * k[2] + b54 * k[3])
    k[5] = h * self.f(t + a6 * h, x + b61 * k[0] + b62 * k[1] + b63 * k[2] + b64 * k[3] + b65 * k[4])
    r = abs( r1 * k[0] + r3 * k[2] + r4 * k[3] + r5 * k[4] + r6 * k[5] ) / h
    r = r / (self.atol+self.rtol*(abs(x)+abs(k[0])))
    if len( np.shape( r ) ) > 0:
        r = max( r )
    if r <= 1:
        t = t + h
        x = x + c1 * k[0] + c3 * k[2] + c4 * k[3] + c5 * k[4]
        T = np.append( T, t )
        X = np.append( X, [x], 0 )
    h = h * min( max( 0.94 * sqrt(sqrt( 1 / r )), 0.1 ), 4.0 )
    if h > self.hmax:
        h = self.hmax
    elif h < self.hmin or t==t-h:
        raise RuntimeError("Error: Could not converge to the required tolerance.")
        break
```

Which works just fine, but I was wondering if is it possible to make this even faster and more efficient?

Comment: I would post this question on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), because your code already works as expected.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang I did not know that such a stack existed! I'll post it there, thanks.

Comment: In case anyone is interested in this question, with the advice of Andy, I asked the same [question in Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/258764/asking-advice-on-optimizing-a-while-loop)